# PHP array print value with specific condition

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

i have an array `$t1` like below :

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [cust_type] => Corporate 
        [trx] => 1 
        [amount] => 10 ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [cust_type] => Non Corporate 
        [trx] => 2 
        [amount] => 20 ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [cust_type] => Corporate 
        [trx] => 3 
        [amount] => 30 ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [cust_type] => Non Corporate 
        [trx] => 4 
        [amount] => 40 ))
```

I want to print `TRX` whose `cust_type = Corporate`. I use conditional statement inside foreach as below :

```
foreach ($t1 as $key => $value) {
        if($value['cust_type'] = 'Corporate')
            {
                print_r($value['trx']);
            }
        echo "<br/>";
    }
```

But it prints all TRX values instead of corporate only. 
Kindly help me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
if($value['cust_type'] == 'Corporate')
```

instead of

```
if($value['cust_type'] = 'Corporate')
```

So the final result will be

```
   foreach ($t1 as $key => $value) {
            if($value['cust_type'] == 'Corporate')
                {
                    print_r($value['trx']);
                }
            echo "<br/>";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use double `==` in place of single `=` in  `if($value['cust_type'] == 'Corporate')`